# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation') Or Inconsistent results in comparison to other navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have an error regarding this piece of code whenever I clicked on one of the rendered rows.

```
renderRow(task, sectionID, rowID, hightlightRow) {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={()=>{
            this.props.navigation.navigate('FavTeams', {login: this.props.navigation.getParam('login', '')});
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{task.teamtag}||{task.teamname}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    )
}
```

However when I tested this.props.navigation.navigate with other pages, this piece of code works just fine with those other buttons. This was the only case where I have problems regarding this piece of code.

The page is AddTeam and this is my route navigation code:

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
{
    Home: {
      screen: Login
    },
    Signup: {
      screen: SignUp
    },
    Dashboard: {
      screen: Dashboard
    },
    FavTeams: {
      screen: FavouriteTeams
    },
    UpcomingGames:{
      screen: UpcomingComponent
    },
    Standings:{
      screen: StandingsComponent
    },
    AddTeam:{
      screen: AddTeams
    }
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
}

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Apparently, `ListView` acts as its own component. So by passing the `this.props.navigation` to one of the parameters used to render the rows, the function can now be used to call to go to other pages.

An example:

```
this.getSomeData().then((response)=>{
    resp = response
    for(someData in response){
        resp[someData].nav = this.props.navigation
    }
    this.setState({
        someDataSource = ListView.DataSource().cloneWithRows(resp)
    })
})
```

By pushing `this.props.navigation`, I can use this as `task.nav`.

```
renderRow(task, sectionID, rowID, hightlightRow) {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={()=>{
            task.nav.navigate('FavTeams', {login: task.user);
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{task.teamtag}||{task.teamname}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    )
}
```

Problem is now, how to pass data to other pages

Answer (score 0):

I believe the underlying problem here is that `navigation` prop was not passed, or not passed correctly to the component you are trying to call it from.

Comment: The thing is, though, the `navigation` prop works well outside of this particular code, even on the same page(or component). This is the only time where `navigation` props doesn't seem to work well. Maybe it has something to do with the `ListView` but I don't really know. I tried passing in other custom functions inside it but it doesn't seem to work well.